# Example using Penetrance & Branching Factor in State-space Heuristic Search

Tags: artificial-intelligence, search-algorithms

I need an example for how to calculate penetrance and branching factor of the search tree in in state-space heuristic search. The definitions are as following. *Penetrance* $P$ is defined by

$\qquad \displaystyle P = \frac{L}{T}$

and *branching factor* $B$ is defined by

$\qquad \displaystyle \frac{B}{(B-1)} \cdot (B^L – 1) = T$

where $L$ is the length of the path from the root to the solution and $T$ the total number of nodes expanded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following search tree. Your heuristic search algorithm starts the search at the root node. Unexpanded nodes are marked gray.

[image: Search tree]

For some reason, the heuristic is being guided towards the left-most subtree, when in fact the goal node is in the right-most subtree, marked with green.

[image: Dead-end]

Nodes that have been expanded are marked red. After the appealing left-most subtree turned out to be a dead-end, the heuristic is now luckily being guided directly towards the goal. From the situation of the previous figure, we'll expand a total of three new nodes before arriving at the goal.

[image: Goal]

From the figure above, the length of the path to the goal is $3$. There are $17$ expanded nodes. Therefore, the **penetrance** is $3/17 \approx 0.43$.

The **branching factor** is the maximum number of successors of any node. For example, the branching factor of a binary tree is $2$ since each node has at most two children. Likewise, in the above search tree the branching factor is $3$.

What you seem to be interested in is not the branching factor, but the **effective branching factor** $B^*$ which is a way to characterize the quality of a heuristic. If the total number of expanded nodes is $T$, and the length of the path to the goal is $L$ (this is more commonly known as *depth*), then $B^*$ is the branching factor that a uniform tree of depth $L$ would have in order to contain $T+1$ nodes. Therefore,

$$T+1 = 1 + B^* + (B^*)^2 + \cdots + (B^*)^L.$$

If you plug-in the values we obtained in search, that is, $T=17$ and $L=3$, you get $B^* \approx 2.165$. This is exactly the same value you get from using your equation; it's just merely a different representation for the same thing.

The effective branching factor can vary across instances, but is somewhat constant for hard enough problems. A well-designed heuristic would have a value of $B^*$ close to $1$, allowing fairly large problems to be solved reasonable cheaply.

Comment: Solving the formula for $B$, you get $B \approx 2.165$. I wonder what the interpretation of that value is. It's close to the average branching factor of all inner nodes, but not the same.

Comment: @MAcad In fact, what you are interested in, is not the branching factor, but the *effective* branching factor which is away to characterize the quality of a heuristic. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Juho I think If I use Branching factor formula I will test many numbers in the LHS and calculate it and check equal with RHS as the following: B=1 ==> 1 + 1 + 1 ^ 2 + 1 ^ 3 = 4 not equal T = 17 so we need to test B=2 ==> 1 + 2 + 2 ^ 2 + 2 ^ 3 = 15 the result near from T so we can test B = 2.1 and so on until reach the result T !!!! I think this formula can use like this :))))